# How to store the submission of forms per user in rails-postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-design, form-submit

I have a `form` with `dynamic questions` and `dynamic input responses` (Response may be a paragraph, a single word, a boolean or array of options)

I need to `store the submission of forms per user`.
Which one is better, like I’m thinking of creating a `submissions` model which belongs_to both `user` and `form` with a `jsonb response column` and store as an `array of hash` which consists of a pair of `question and response` by the user.

Or

Should I map the response to each question and store them inside a answers model belongs to submissions model?

Comment: Simply you want to create the records from whom the forms are submitted. Please clarify to your questions

Comment: I need to create the record to store the response of the questions (answers provided by the user who submits), the details who submitted the form. Also I need to generate a score report based on the answers provided. These are the main requirements. @cryptex-technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends.

If the Form is a strong entity, that will not be destroyed when the user is deleted. Then embed it in `json` field is not an option.

If the Form is a weak entity, and will only be accessed along with the user. You may store it on a `json` field.